# Features.feature in SharePoint app

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, feature

I added a new SharePoint app project into an existing web project solution. When I tried to deploy it am getting an error:

```
Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': 
Failed to install app for SharePoint. 
There was a problem with activating the app web definition.
```

But when I removed the feature1.feature file, it is geeting deployed successfully.

1. What is the reason?
2. Is there any better solution?
3. What is this feature1.feature file for?

Answer (score 1):

1. I guess the reason is, SharePoint app have web scoped feature [you can not change it,because app is nothing just a 'web'] and your web project have some different feature scope.
2. Better solution if you have webscope app based functionality then choose app project and if it is required then only you link up your app with web project by Properties-->Web -->Project Url.
3. http://books.google.co.in/books?id=DdM3yNb13goC&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=feature1.feature+file+in+Sharepoint+2010&source=bl&ots=3FyJWmJHOZ&sig=f9ymz-dZrhrPcnHRYyBQWHqzS3M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FoGlUvq5MZGsrAevjoCgBA&ved=0CHYQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=feature1.feature%20file%20in%20Sharepoint%202010&f=false

   https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/visual-studio-2010-and-sharepoint-2010-support-at-last/